# Including dates with zero rows in ddply

Tags: r

I am using ddply from the plyr package to get a count of rows by date. However, when there are dates with no values, they are disregarded and I end up a data frame where certain dates are no present. I'm ussing the values generated by ddply to generate a plot and wanted to find how I could include all dates which weren't present, and give them a nrow value of 0.

```
library(plyr)
f = ddply(df, .(created), "nrow")
f = as.data.frame(f)

> head(f)
     created nrow
1 2009-12-29    2
2 2009-12-30    3
3 2010-01-06    1
4 2010-01-07    2
5 2010-01-08    2
6 2010-01-11    1
```

To properly construct the line plot, I'd like to have all the dates (those with 0 nrow values). So in the above segment, I want to add all missing dates such as '2010-01-01' to '2010-01-05' and give each an nrow value of 9. Can't anyone suggest an elegant way to perform this task.

```
ggplot(f, aes(x=created, y=nrow)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.6, color="darkgreen") +
  labs(title="Plot") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(family="sans", face="bold"),  
        axis.text.x=element_text(family="sans", face="bold"))
```

I thought the .drop command in ddply performed this task, but it doesn't seem to do so.

EDIT:

Sample data.

```
mdf=data.frame(created=c('2009-12-29','2009-12-30','2010-01-06','2010-01-07',
                     '2010-01-08','2010-01-11','2009-12-29','2009-12-30'))

ddply(mdf, .(created), .drop=FALSE, "nrow")



    created nrow
1 2009-12-29    2
2 2009-12-30    2
3 2010-01-06    1
4 2010-01-07    1
5 2010-01-08    1
6 2010-01-11    1
```

How can I get '2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', etc to be included with values of 0 for nrow.

Comment: Could you provide us with sample `df` so that I can spare myself the time to construct the data myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use an object of appropriate class

Since you want the plot, it is enough to provide the date as class "Date".

```
# Load libraries
library(package=plyr)
library(package=ggplot2)

# Create data
mdf <- data.frame(created=c('2009-12-29','2009-12-30','2010-01-06','2010-01-07',
                     '2010-01-08','2010-01-11','2009-12-29','2009-12-30'))
mdf$created <- as.Date(mdf$created)

# Plot with variable of class "Date"
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=created)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.6, color="darkgreen", stat='bin', binwidth=1) +
  labs(title="Plot") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(family="sans", face="bold"),  
        axis.text.x=element_text(family="sans", face="bold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward way is to create another `data.frame` with all the dates using the `min` and  `max` of the result from `ddply`:

```
# dummy data.frame
set.seed(45)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-03-31"), by=3)
df <- data.frame(created=sample(dates, 100, replace=T))
# your plyr result
require(plyr)
df.r <- ddply(df, .(created), nrow) # 30 * 2

# solution:
df2 <- data.frame(created = seq(min(df.r$created), max(df.r$created), by=1), V1 = 0)
idx <- match(df2$created, df.r$created)
df2$V1[!is.na(idx)] <- df.r$V1[idx[!is.na(idx)]]
```

Now, `df2` would have all dates with `0's` for those dates that were missing in `df.r`. I am not sure if this is "elegant" though!

Answer (score 3):

You can preapre a list with all dates (sequence), then merge with your table date. this will insert NA in the original data.

```
dd <- ddply(mdf,.(created),nrow)
df.miss <- data.frame(created=seq.Date(min(dd$created),max(dd$created),1))
dat <- merge(dd,df.miss,all.y=T)
dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0  ## I replace NA by 0 here
```

Now I plot my data

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(V1~created,data=dat, type=c('l','p'),cex=2,lty=2)
```

[image]